# JSON_SEARCH difference in MySQL and MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, json-search

I just try to get path of value using `JSON_SEARCH` function:

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH('[12, 13, {"12": 123}]', 'one', '123', null, '$[*]') path;
```

When I run this query in MariaDB [it works](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=4d1324ac5d5578b22c8b5f8367f955a7&php_version=null&sql_version=mariadb) and I got desired result

```
+===========+
| path      |
+===========+
| "$[2].12" |
+-----------+
```

but run same query on top MySQL 8.0 I [got NULL](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=4d1324ac5d5578b22c8b5f8367f955a7&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

So I need help how to match the query for use it with MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bug #79233: JSON_SEARCH does not search for non-string values](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79233)

If your JSON scalar values are strings, you can find them:

```
mysql> SELECT JSON_SEARCH('[12, 13, {"12": "123"}]', 'one', '123', null, '$[*]') path;
                                           ^^^^^ quoted string value
+---------------+
| path          |
+---------------+
| "$[2].\"12\"" |
+---------------+
```

Comment: And https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90085 is the feature request to make this work.