# Why is my JSON_REMOVE working on MariaDB but not MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

It seems to me they are the same in both docs. But on MySQL it says 0 rows affected. The command does run but doesn't change anything.
I have 2 databases, a local one which uses 10.4.22-MariaDB and one hosted on Heroku which uses 8.0.23 (MySQL)
I am using MySQL workbench for both, not sure why MariaDB is installed anyways since I always intended to use MySQL but they're basically the same

So I have this JSON_REMOVE command, and it doesnt work on my Heroku-hosted database which uses 8.0.23 MySQL with JawsDB add-on.

My question is, how can I make this work on MySQL as well? It should work there as far as I can tell.
I replace the arrow brackets with real values of course.
`users` is the users table
`followings` is a column of type JSON (array)

```sql
-- remove specific postID from user's json array
UPDATE users
SET followings = JSON_REMOVE(followings, replace(json_search(followings, 'one', <postID>), '"', ''))
WHERE json_search(followings, 'one', <postID>) IS NOT NULL
AND username = "<username>";
```

Here is a sample data of the users Table

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(45) UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR(45),
    role VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT "user",
    followings JSON DEFAULT '[]' COMMENT "array of post IDs which user follows"
);

INSERT INTO users
(username, password, role, followings)
VALUES
('user123', 'mypass', 'user', '[1, 2]')
```

Comment: Hi, it woudl be useful if you showed us at least an example of the data this is processing

Comment: Why should I provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example for any SQL query question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @RiggsFolly kk edited to include data sample

Comment: Your code looks working on MariaDB 10.5: https://sqlize.online/sql/mariadb/730419cf0f4ae7f9fd469201a28e10e3/

Comment: That is a nightmare way of storing a list of posts a user is following. You are using a Relational database, its designed for storing the type of information using a link table. That will also make processing (adding/removing) links a completely simple process, whereas using a JSON string in a column is a bad and often Overly Complex way

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev it works on my Maria (the version is stated) , but not on my MySQL 8.0x
that is my issue, i need to make it work on MySQL as well , and it only works on my Maria

Comment: Did you check the MySQL docs about [JSON_REMOVE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-remove)?

Comment: @RiggsFolly you're right I do regret going this route lol. But a little late for me to go back on this project since its due in a couple of days. Anyways it is working perfectly fine , just MySQL production host is not working the same as Maria for whatever reason

Comment: This is looks as MySQL bug. Look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68882785/json-search-difference-in-mysql-and-mariadb

Comment: BTW: your `CREATE TABLE` does not work on MySQL, and your `INSERT` is not working on MySQL and MariaDB .

Comment: 4 column names - 6 inputs??? Lets try some real data that matches the CREATE and also the JSON_REMOVE

Answer (score 0):

A solution (not a nice one) could be to define your own function like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `MY_JSON_REMOVE`(j JSON, i INT) RETURNS json
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
     select json_arrayagg(c1) into j from json_table(j,'$[*]' columns(c1 JSON PATH "$[0]")) j where c1 <> i;
RETURN j;
END
```

Doing: `select my_json_remove('[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]',3);`

Returns: `[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]`

Because overriding a MySQL function seems not possible, you will have to use `MY_JSON_REMOVE()` (or whatever name you give it).